# Hibernate twice embedded entities

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, mapping

I have Hibernate 5.2.10 version and hibernate-jpa-2.1-api with version 1.0.0.Final. I am using MairaDB as database. In persistance.xml, set the property hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy as DefaultComponentSafeNamingStrategy but still I receive the same error:
Repeated column in mapping for entity. I do not want to use @attributeoverrides hibernate and I tried different methodes but still the same error. I want two or more embedded enities.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `DefaultComponentSafeNamingStrategy` with Hibernate 5, because of it is an implementation of the old `NamingStrategy` interface from Hibernate 4.

As you probably know, Hibernate 5 uses two new interfaces `ImplicitNamingStrategy` and `PhysicalNamingStrategy`.

You can use this implicit naming strategy: `org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyComponentPathImpl`.
You will need to set `hibernate.implicit_naming_strategy` property (**not** `hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy`).

For these entities

```
@Embeddable
public class AuthorInfo {

    @Column
    private String authorInfo;

    @OneToOne
    private Book bestBook;

}

@Entity
public class Book {

    @Id
    private Long pid;

    @Embedded
    private AuthorInfo firstAuthor;

    @Embedded
    private AuthorInfo secondAuthor;

}
```

it creates this schema

```
create table Book (
        pid bigint not null,
        firstAuthor_authorInfo varchar(255),
        secondAuthor_authorInfo varchar(255),
        firstAuthor_bestBook_pid bigint,
        secondAuthor_bestBook_pid bigint,
        primary key (pid)
)
```

Unit test to check a schema: [TwoEmbeddedStrategyTest.java](https://github.com/v-ladynev/hibernate-experimental/blob/master/src/test/java/com/github/experimental/strategy/embedded/TwoEmbeddedStrategyTest.java)

Comment: I used annotation @column and used this org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyComponentPathImpl and did not work but after removing annotations it worked.

Comment: @Elhamo I have checked this with Hibernate SessionFactory, not with PersistentContext. It can be a reason, but I am not sure. You could just miss something.

Comment: @v.ladynev My experience is that if you use the `org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyComponentPathImpl` strategy then `@Column` is ignored (specifically the name value).  Is there a way to use this strategy while preserving the use of `@Column`?  This problem might be what @Elhamo was describing.

Comment: @mbmast @Column is ignored with `PhysicalNamingStrategy`. It shouldn't be ignored with `ImplicitNamingStrategy`, as I can remember.

Comment: PhysicalNamingStrategy only contains information on the column. How am I to detect if the naming applies to a certain field of a certain class or embeddable type. Containz zero useful information. Just column name through identifier.getText().